# What Sharepoint Server Hosting provider would you suggest?

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-hosting, microsoft, sharepoint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

We run an international organisation that is looking at implementing MS SharePoint.

Who would you suggest we use? Currently we are looking at: Verio, Rackspace, SherWeb.

In particular we're hoping for a reliable provider that has better international connectivity. Server uptime and service responsiveness are our main key requirements.

Greg

Answer (score 4):

I think anyone who can provide decent windows hosting will suffice. My vote would be for Rackspace.

One other thing I've just remembered: Rackspace do [managed sharepoint hosting](http://www.rackspace.co.uk/email-apps/sharepoint/) (although I don't know if managed is the right word) so you don't have to worry about any of the hosting.

Comment: Thats Piers, Rackspace have a good offering and definitely looking into them. Only downside is they only offer ver 2007, not 2010 yet. Only alternative is SherWeb.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to self promote but we at www.sharepointhosting.uk.com offer a shared 2010 hosted solution with the data kept in the UK - not something you will find easily!

Prices start at £9per user per month (decreasing with volume).

Feel free to enquire or email for more information

Comment: Thank you for being upfront and honest about your affiliation. The StackExchange network has had a long standing problem with certain service providers (one Sharepoint webhost in particular was spamming their link from different accounts) posting fake testimonials and being dishonest about their affiliation with the service they're recommending.

Answer (score 0):

you can also loot at microsoft online services.  Sharepoint sucks so bad, I would look into a cleaner alternative such as Box.net.  I love MSFT but hate BizTalk, SharePoint, and their CRM.

I use MSFT online services for exchange, and also have rackspace for exchange.  Rackspace is a lot NICER, but MSFT online services may give you more.  Check them out.

Comment: Thanks Frank, however box.net only offers a cloud file sharing service, and we need the full range of services that Sharepoint offers.

Comment: We use box.net with HighRise

Comment: I steer clear of Microsoft platforms most of the time, but it seems like Sharepoint has a lot of integration with Microsoft Office that would be hard for competitors to match.